# Odoo POS multiple barcode scan

Tags: barcode, scanning

am trying to configure POS in odoo for a butchery shop,

the scaled meat products come from the scale with a priced barcode

but it has two checksum,

for example

0200011021196

which is divided as follow

02 (department code) 0001 (product ID or known as PLU) 1 checksum for the weight 02119 (price of the mean which is 21.19) 6 is the barcode checksum digit,

in this situation, the weight checksum in the middle has ten possibilities from 0 to 9

and the last checksum also has  ten possibilities from 0 to 9

these two checksum make 10 x 10 = 100

which means 100 multiple barcodes for a single type of meat,

the butchery has like 40 meats, sheen, Tbone, checking .... etc

then 100 x 40 = 4000 barcodes,

loading them in the POS system makes it very slow,

is there a way to configure the Barcode Nomenclatures to ignore transmitting both

check sum and read only the product ID and the price. ?

your support is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a standard EAN/UPC barcode?

Comment: Have you changed Odoo's barcode logic? The standard format for barcodes containing a weight is `21 XXXXX WWWWW C`. I guess you either need to change the barcodes printed by the scale, or change Odoo's logic for looking up barcodes. Otherwise you will have to register all possible weights...

Comment: Changing the barcode printed from the scale is not possible, as the scale is old fashion and have limited options. From odoo settings, is there away to force the Nomenclature setting to ignore reading the last digit which is known as the checksum.     I am currently loading 100 barcode possiblities for every meat type, and with total of 40 meats and checking, the system is loading almost 40 X 100 = 4000 barcodes which is making it very slow.    any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: So you will have to modify the barcode logic. Otherwise 4,000,000 products are needed (40 products times 100,000 different weights). Supposedly you'll have to override the `parse_ean()` method of the `point_of_sale.BarcodeReader` class located in `addons/point_of_sale/static/src/js/devices.js` (says the forum on https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/what-kind-of-barcodes-are-supported-by-the-point-of-sale-53).

Comment: You might get away with defining a barcode nomenclature like so `02.....NNNDD` (see https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/applications/inventory_and_mrp/inventory/barcode/operations/barcode_nomenclature.html). It should then be sufficient to register the same meat 10 times, e.g. `0200010`, `0200011`, ... `0200019`, i.e. with all possible weight checksums. There is no need to do the same for the standardized EAN checksum at the end. Possibly the EAN must be registered with the full 13 digits (incl. the EAN checksum digit), e.g. `0200010000001` instead of `0200010`.

Comment: as you said, I will have to work with 10 possiblities for the weight checksum, that is ok, ten barcodes for each meat type, but I need to find a solution to ignore the very last checksum digit. I have gone through both links and followed those intructions, but either the system rejects reading, or it will read with check sum, I even tried approaching the last checksum as part of the decimal numbers, the problem that customers were getting charged 10 pencse extra everytime the checksum is higher then 5, as odoo tends to round the figure to nearest higher number.

Comment: Did you set the nomenclature type to EAN-13? The last digit is the EAN-13 check digit. So I would expect that it will be ignored by Odoo if it knows it's an EAN-13. Possibly your problem is that checksum calculation. 0200011021196 is not a valid EAN-13. The checksum is incorrect.

Comment: The barcode mentioned in my article is not real one, I have just written it myself, but here is a real barcode generated from the scale 0200015002567 please let me know if this will make my enquiry clearer